# Capture audio with VBA and ffmpeg

Tags: vba, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm trying to get the audio with the following VBA and ffmpeg code. It states on the first line that: The syntax for the file name, directory name or volume label is incorrect, but the path and file names are not incorrect

```
Sub ExtractTextFromMP3()
  Dim mp3FilePath As String
  Dim outputFilePath As String
  Dim ffmpegPath As String
  Dim command As String

' Set the paths
  mp3FilePath = "C:\Temp\ed.mp3"
  outputFilePath = "C:\Temp\ed.txt"
  ffmpegPath = "C:\Temp\bin\ffmpeg.exe" ' Path to your FFmpeg executable

' Construct the FFmpeg command  
  command = """" & ffmpegPath & """" & " -i """ & mp3FilePath & """ -f s16le -acodec pcm_s16le -vn -ar 44100 -ac 2 - | " & _
      """" & ffmpegPath & """" & " -f s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 -i - -acodec pcm_s16le -f wav - | " & _
      """" & ffmpegPath & """" & " -i - -f segment -segment_time 30 -c copy -vn -y """ & outputFilePath & """"

' Execute the FFmpeg command
  Shell "cmd /c " & command ', vbHide
End Sub
```

This throws the following error:

```
[aist#0:0/pcm_s16le @ 00000276950ee240] Guessed Channel Layout: stereo
Input #0, s16le, from 'fd:':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le, 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_s16le (native) -> pcm_s16le (native))
[aost#0:0/pcm_s16le @ 0000027695101600] No filtered frames for 
output stream, trying to initialize anyway.
Output #0, wav, to 'pipe:':
Metadata:
ISFT            : Lavf60.10.100
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 1411 kb/s
Metadata:
  encoder         : Lavc60.22.100 pcm_s16le
[out#0/wav @ 0000027695100800] video:0kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB 
other streams:0kB global 
headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[out#0/wav @ 0000027695100800] Output file is empty, nothing was encoded(check -ss / -t / -frames parameters if used)
size=       0kB time=N/A bitrate=N/A speed=N/A
[wav @ 000001ea21a9f800] Ignoring maximum wav data size, file may be invalid
[wav @ 000001ea21a9f800] Cannot check for SPDIF
[aist#0:0/pcm_s16le @ 000001ea21a9e280] Guessed Channel Layout: stereo
Input #0, wav, from 'fd:':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf60.10.100
Duration: N/A, bitrate: 1411 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_s16le ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 44100 Hz, 2 channels, s16, 1411 kb/s
Output #0, segment, to 'C:\Temp\ed.txt':
[out#0/segment @ 000001ea21ad9140] Output file does not contain any stream
Error opening output file C:\Temp\ed.txt.
Error opening output files: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Do you have write permission on C:\Temp ?

Comment: Yes I have write permission

Comment: I tried this line, and it gives me the same error as the first line of code above: The syntax for the filename, directory name, or volume label is incorrect.

cmd /c "C:\Temp\bin\ffmpeg.exe" ffmpeg -dump_attachment:t:0 "C:\Temp\ed.txt" -i "C:\Temp\ed.mp3"

Comment: What I want is to extract the text from the audio

Comment: I have no clue about ffmpeg - I just know that using C:\Temp is often a problem as it is write protected. In Windows, you should use %temp% (in VBA, use `Environ("Temp")` )

Comment: Does your command work if you enter it directly on the command line? - forget the VBA until that's working.

Comment: @ Tim Williams: 
Doesn't work in cmd command line

Comment: In that case not really a VBA question?

Comment: I'm using VBA and ffmpeg, according to the title of the post and according to the code shown... I did the test in cmd to see what error it is returning since in vba it doesn't return any error

Comment: I can see you're using VBA, but the root problem is the command line syntax, not the VBA.

Comment: The ideal thing was that it was all in vba, but as no one answered me in the other post, so I'm accepting some kind of command line, but without success!!